# How to avoid explicit validation of req.user.id everytime with typescript?

Tags: typescript, passport.js

Using `passportjs` with `typescript` everytime I have to use `req.user.<property>` explicity have to validate `req.isAuthenticated()` so I created a middleware function to use it everywhere when needed.

The thing is that `typescript` don't recognize this behavior

`routes/index.ts`

```
import { Router } from 'express'

import create from './create'

const router = Router({
  mergeParams: true
})

// Create new list endpoint
router.post('/', create)
```

`middlewares/isAuthenticated.ts`

```
export default function isAuthenticated(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next()
  }

  req.flash('warning', 'You need to login first to acces this page')

  req.Inertia.redirect('/auth/login')
}
```

`routes/create.ts`

```
async function create(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
  const payload = <iPayload>req.body

  const knex = Knex()

  await knex('public.lists')
    .insert({
      title: payload.title,
      // Next line typescript throws: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
      user_id: req.user.id 
      // Have to "fix it" using: user_id: req.user ? req.user.id : null
    })

    req.Inertia.redirect(`/lists`)
}

export default [isAuthenticated, create]
```

One "easy" thing to do is to validate it everywhere I need to use `req.user` but I looks ugly and tedious to me.

```
if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    await knex('public.lists').insert({
        title: payload.title,
        user_id: req.user.id
    })
}
```

Any clues on how to fix this?

By the way, I defined the user type like this:

```
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface User {
      id: number;
      email: string;
      username: string;
      name: string;
      picture: string | null;
      
    }
  }
}

export {};
```

Comment: The simplest solution would be: `user_id: req.user!.id`

Comment: Is this the same effect as `user_id: req.user ? req.user.id : null`?

Comment: No, it's telling Typescript to ignore the fact that user is nullable. So if `req.user` is null, it would throw a `TypeError` exception

Comment: @SergioFlores If you want that behaviour, you could write: `user_id: req.user?.id`. But you pointed out that the code in question is not reachable, because of your logic. That's why I suggested the other syntax first.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. What did you end up using?